# Next/link is not responding nextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, vercel

I figured out it is showing 5-10 second delay sometimes it does not load the page, and when click back the URL is changing but the content are not re-rendering. and when I try normal   it works as expected. I don't know, is this a bug of Next/link ?

I can see the URL in the bottom-left of browser that is linked to the tab when I hover over but click does not work. Is there any issue with SSR of CSR? Or is this because of dev environment? or because of project size?

This is the code of SideNavigation:

```
export default function SideNavigation() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const { isCollapsed, toggleSidebarcollapse } = useContext(SidebarContext);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 relative ml-3">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center py-1 rounded-md mt-2">
        <Image src={logo} alt={""} width={28} height={28} />
        <b className={`text-xl ml-3 ${isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"}`}>
          APP NAME
        </b>
      </div>

      <div
        className="absolute rounded-r-full w-5 h-8 -right-[21px] top-20 bg-black flex justify-center items-center"
        onClick={toggleSidebarcollapse}
      >
        {isCollapsed ? (
          <AiFillCaretRight color="white" />
        ) : (
          <AiFillCaretLeft color="white" />
        )}
      </div>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab1"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          }  items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/home"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <BiSolidHomeSmile size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab1
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>

      <div
        className={`h-[0.5px] py-1 border-t-[0.5px] border-zinc-600 ${
          !isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
        }`}
      ></div>
      <h1
        className={`pl-8 text-sm text-zinc-400 ${
          isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
        }`}
      >
        SERVICES
      </h1>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab2"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/analytics"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <IoMdAnalytics size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab2
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab3"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/financial"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <MdPayments size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab 3
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab4"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/payroll"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <MdOutlineCurrencyExchange size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab 4
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab5"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/legal-consulting"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <FaHammer size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab 5
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div
        className={`h-[0.5px] py-1 border-t-[0.5px] border-zinc-600 ${
          !isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
        }`}
      ></div>
      <h1
        className={`pl-8 text-sm text-zinc-400 ${
          isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
        }`}
      >
        GENERAL
      </h1>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab6"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/customization"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <MdDashboardCustomize size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab 6
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>

      <Link href={"/dashboard/tab7"}>
        <div
          className={`flex pl-4 pr-4 gap-2 text-sm ${
            isCollapsed ? "justify-center" : "justify-start"
          } items-center rounded-lg py-2 ${
            pathname == "/dashboard/settings"
              ? "bg-green-600 text-zinc-950"
              : "hover:bg-zinc-800"
          }`}
        >
          <AiTwotoneSetting size={22} />
          <h1
            className={`text-sm font-semibold ml-1 ${
              isCollapsed ? "hidden" : "visible"
            }`}
          >
            Tab 7
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```